# HelloTabWidget must be force closed unexpectedly on emulator

Tags: android

I created the HelloTabWidget tutorial app for android and cannot seem to make it work.  I get a warning saying the application was closed or stopped unexpectedly.  The console only logs that the activity is being initiated but it stays there.  The app is successfully installed on the emulator but nothing else.

Ive uploaded my code here:

www.santiapps.com/HelloTabWidget.zip

I would appreciate if you could look over the code and point out if you see anything that might be the problem.  Im running it on an eclipse helios, on an avd min7, target12 and max12.  Ive run helloworld on the same avd and it runs fine.

What can I do to figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of match_parent requires at least Android 8.  Use fill_parent to support pre-8.

Further, the manifest says android:minSdkVersion="11".

Since the "drawable" resource directory is empty, this will not work on Android 3.

Since only the "drawable-hdpi" resource directory has all of the necessary resources, this will not work on MDPI or LDPI devices.

Does that help point you in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks but Im a little bit more confused.  But let me try and interpret: (1) match_parent I assume is some command that you say only works with versions 8+.  You give me an option for <8.  But I set my target sdk for 12, which is greater than 8, so why would i need to change that? (2) yes manifest says minSDK11.  Why is that a problem if Im using 11 as the target?  I understand about there being 3 drawable directories, but the tutorial didnt specify which of the 3.  Should i just put a copy in all 3 directories?

Comment: When you said, "on an avd min7, target12 and max12," I interpreted that this might mean that you're trying to run this an emulator with Android 7.  Just specifying a minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion in the manifest doesn't stop eclipse from letting you deploy the application to a lesser versioned emulator or device.  http://goo.gl/Ufjqc  If you're sure that the emulator you're using is running Android 12, then what screen resolution does it have?  If it has a screen resolution of HDPI, then you don't need to make any changes to the drawable directories.